# How to put python variables into an SQL statement?

Tags: python, database, sqlite, authentication

I'm quite a beginner to SQL so I'm probably missing something import, but I'll ask anyway:

I'm creating a login program using an SQL database in python using SQLite3. When trying to check if a security question is correct I use these lines of code:

```
py_Username = input()
Answer1 = input()
if Answer1 == Cursor.execute("SELECT Security_Question1 FROM UserInfo WHERE Username = " + py_Username):
```

When doing this I get this error and don't know why...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    if Answer1 == Cursor.execute("SELECT Security_Question1 FROM UserInfo WHERE Username = " + py_Username):
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: jake9
```

Please Help! Thanks.

Comment: Is jake9 your test input?? And in addition, the Cursor.execute() should return a list, I guess, making your check problematic.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking the value Answer1 with the return value `Cursor.execute()` function which is wrong.
Note that to access the tuple data you need to use `Cursor.fetchall()` and then iterate through it. Try experimenting with the following code and refer the documentation.

````
```lang-python```
 records = Cursor.execute("Statement")
 for row in records:
     print(row)
````